# How can I properly use Pyenv and venv?

Tags: python, pyenv, python-venv

Articles read:

[Python Virtual Environments: A Primer](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/),

[Pyenv – Install Multiple Python Versions for Specific Project](https://www.tecmint.com/pyenv-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-in-linux/),

[How to manage multiple Python versions and virtual environments](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f)

Let's suppose we have these directories:

- `~/Projects/PyA`: uses Python 3.4.3 with Django 2.0
- `~/Projects/PyB`: uses Python 3.5.1 with Django 2.1
- `~/Projects/PyC`: uses Python 3.5.6 with Django 2.2
- `~/Projects/PyD`: uses Python 3.2 with python-igraph

The first to do, we install the Python versions needed:

```
pyenv install 3.4.3
pyenv install 3.5.1
pyenv install 3.5.6
pyenv install 3.2
```

**My questions start here:**

Should I do this?

```
cd ~/Projects/PyA && pyenv local 3.4.3 && python3.4 -m venv proA
cd ~/Projects/PyB && pyenv local 3.5.1 && python3.5 -m venv proB
cd ~/Projects/PyC && pyenv local 3.5.6 && python3.5 -m venv proC
cd ~/Projects/PyD && pyenv local 3.2 && python3.2 -m venv proD
```

When is a unique directory for virtual environments used? Which option is recommended? Why?

How should I install the per-project packages listed above?

Should I use `virtualenvwrapper`?

How do I switch between projects (changing Python/virtual-environment in the process) easily or painlessly?

In Ruby, there is a file named `Gemfile` where I can set which gems (with their respective versions) are installed for the current project, which is a very good idea. Is there something similar for Python?

PS: I use [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) as *guest* for a [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29) box.

Comment: I just edited my answer to hopefully address all your questions. If there is anything unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 17):

> When is an unique directory for virtual environments used? Which
> option is recommended? Why?

Every virtual environment "lives" in its own folder. All packages you install will go there, especially if every environment will have a different Python version.

---

> How should I install per-project packages listed above?

When you switch to the project environment after you created it, see my original answer below. All packages installed will exclusively be installed into that virtual environment you are currently working in.

You can always check which Python interpreter is currently in use by typing

```
which python
```

in the terminal you currently have the the project environment activated. In addition you can also check

```
which pip
```

to make sure if you are installing using `pip install somepackage` that you target the correct Python interpreter. If you want to pin the packages, you can do

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

any time and the currently installed packages plus their version will be written to the textfile `requirements.txt`. You can now always create a new environment using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

> Should I use virtualenvwrapper?

I would always work in a per-project virtual environment, so other projects that may use some pinned version of a special package are not influenced.

> How do I switch between projects (changing Python/virtual-environment
> in the process) easily or painlessly?

You could define an alias in your [~/.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) or `~/.bash_aliases`. In a terminal, open (in my example) the `~/.bashrc` with a text editor, e.g., [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)/[nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) or one of your liking:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and somewhere near the end you can add a line with an alias to switch to the project directory and activate the environment at the same time:

```
alias activate_proj1="cd ~/project_1 && pyenv activate venv_project_1"
```

so you only type `activate_proj1` in the terminal (tab completion also works) and both commands are executed. Don't forget to source the bash-file again after you change something with `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal.

---

*Original answer:*

`pyenv` will handle everything you need:

My workflow (for one project to make it more readable) would be the following:

```
pyenv install 3.5.1
cd python_projects
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
pyenv virtualenv 3.5.1 venv_myproject
```

After that you can simply activate the virtualenv created by `pyenv` using

```
pyenv activate venv_myproject
```

which will open your distinct environment. Here you can do all the things you want, e.g., install your packages using pip etc.
After you completed setting up the environment, you can freeze the environment and create a requirements file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to be able to reconstruct the environment if needed. This way all the overhead that may be needed (setting a PATH etc.) will be handled by pyenv.

If you want to work on different projects, just activate the environment you need and off you go!

Note that you can make [`pyenv` activate the virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) when you `cd` the folder in your terminal by putting its name into your `.python-version` file as well.

Comment: Thanks, your answer cleared me some doubts, I've been practicing with some cases and I have come to the following conclusion: if you want per-project virtual environments (my case) then is better to use "pyenv local" & "pyenv -m venv", otherwise use "pyenv virtualenv" or "virtualenvwrapper".

Comment: It's better to use "pyenv which python" instead of only "which python"

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on in this question.

[virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) workflows are usually pretty simple. You create a directory for your project, cd into it, and run `virtualenv venv` for a simple virtualenv, but you can also specify which Python executable you'd like in your virtual environment with a `-p python3.5` for a Python 3.5 virtual environment, for instance.

There isn’t any magic going on here. You need Python 3.5 installed to create the Python 3.5 virtual environment. To activate this virtual environment, you simply `source venv/bin/activate`. Once activated, your shell should reflect which virtual environment you're operating in. You can even run `which python` to see that it's actually directed at the `venv` directory structure. Simple.

An analog to the Gemfile in Python would be similar to what most projects use as a `requirements.txt`. These can be generated trivially by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or installed by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Generally, this is done within the context of a virtual environment to avoid disrupting or clobbering your operating system's global Python packages.

Kenneth Reitz released a tool that incorporates virtualenv called [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and it looks very nice, but I've had some trouble breaking my habits of using virtualenv, and the truth is, virtualenv hasn't presented me with enough problems to deeply explore this new project, but your mileage may vary. Mr. Reitz's contributions to the Python community are overwhelmingly positive, so it's definitely worth a look.

Comment: Looking back at your question, I suppose if I really needed to run more than a version or two of python, I'd probably be using virtual machines or docker containers, and use the system's python site-packages instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small instruction manual.

From installing to Activating/Deactivating

Install `pyenv`

> curl https://pyenv.run | bash

Add these lines to `.bashrc` and `source` this file:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

# Restart your shell for the changes to take effect.

# Load pyenv-virtualenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bashrc:

eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

> source ~/.bashrc

Install `gcc` if build essential fails:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

> Degraded the package (if there is an issue in installing pyenv)
> sudo apt install libc6=2.35-0ubuntu3

Supporting packages:

```
sudo apt install -y zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

To list all the packages:

> pyenv install -l

Install specific Python version:

> pyenv install 3.8.6

See all Python versions in pyenv:

> pyenv versions

Select that Python version:

> pyenv local <python_version>

To create virtual env:
This will create venv somewhere in root, from there you can activate and deactivate it

> pyenv virtualenv  
> pyenv virtualenv 3  venv

Activating

> pyenv local myproject

pyenv deactivate

Issue with `mysqlclient`

> sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
> pip3 install mysqlclient

Comment: The advice to downgrade `libc6` is spurious and potentially quite damaging. ***Absolutely don't* do this** unless you know what you are doing and have good recent backups.