# How to use a specific python version at venv creation?

Tags: python, configuration, virtualenv, python-venv, pyvenv

I'd like to be able to specify in a file the python version to use for my project in order to retrieve it automatically at venv creation.

I manage to specify it manually but wonder if I could retrieve it from a conf file in the repo using that kind of trick:

```
python{my_version} -m venv .venv
```

Comment: Not possible. Some additional tools might help with that tough. But asking for tool recommendations is out of scope for StackOverflow. These tools are easy to find anyway, and which one you should pick can only be decided by you, not by StackOverflow members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I properly use Pyenv and venv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731543/how-can-i-properly-use-pyenv-and-venv)